# How does Wicket's @SpringBean annotation work?

Tags: java, spring, wicket

How does Wicket's `@SpringBean` annotation work?  Does it use reflection at run time?  Does it make the compiler inject some code?  Or what?

Comment: There is no `@SpringBean` annotation in the Spring API. There is one in Wicket, though, is that what you're using?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that - yes I am using Wicket.  I'll change the question and tags to reflect that.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tarquila - I think it's easier to fix this question for spring. And add a new one for Wicket.

Comment: I think the accepted answer for this question should be changed.  @skaffman's answer seems to be the true correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring uses the class loader and ASM at runtime to find all annotated classes.

You can [configure](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) where spring should search for beans:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.package.to.start.from"/>
```

This uses the [ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.html) internally which will use the [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) to find the classes and the ASM-based [MetadataReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/type/classreading/MetadataReader.html) to read the annotations.

Comment: This mechanism doesn't have anything to do with `@SpringBean`, though, which is a Wicket construct, not a Spring one.

Comment: I've never used Wicket. I thought he meant the @Component etc. annotations. Good to know.

Answer (score 29):

`@SpringBean` works using Wicket's [underlying Injector mechanism](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Spring). When you instantiate a Wicket component, the constructor of Wicket's component base class introspects the class being instantiated, looking for the `@SpringBean` annotation. If the bean is found, then Wicket generates a proxy for the spring bean and injects it into the component's field. This is Wicket's equivalent of Spring's `@Autowired` annotation, the effect is similar.

It doesn't, however, have anything to do with Spring's own context/classpath scanning functionality (e.g. `@Component`), which is about auto-discovery of what is and isn't a bean, rather having anything to do with wiring.

Comment: To use this one only needs to add the SpringComponentInjector listener to the Wicket application to listen to component instantiations.

Answer (score 5):

The class marked with a @SpringBean annotation has to have one of:

1. A no-args constructor
2. A superclass with a no-args constructor
3. Implement an interface

An exception will be thrown if these conditions are not met as Wicket will not be able to proxy the class.

Comment: this is useful information but not really an answer to the question.  it might be better as a comment the question or another answer.